# React.js State is updated if the component is re-rendered by updating props?

Tags: reactjs

Can I keep the same state in component even after re-rendered triggered by changing props?

Here is the scenario.
I have 2 components - Table and TablePagination and Wrapper for these.

```
<Container>
  <Table />
  <TablePagination handlePagination={this.handlePagination} />
</Container>
```

I have a table and I keep the selected rowIds in this.state.selected to make them highlighted.

when I change the page from tablePagination, Table's state got updated and I'm losing selected ids from this.state.selected.

I wanna keep them even after page is updated fro tablePagination.

Thanks

PS: I've figured out that state is not updated after component is re-rendered from @Hector's comment.

Thanks all.

Comment: Re-render is performed when state changes. What do you mean?

Comment: State and Props are 2 different things and are per default not affected by eachother. Updating your props doesn't affect your state unless you excplicitly program your app to do so. Can you show us some code?

Comment: let's say I have this.state.A and this.state.B. I wanna keep the state.A as it was before even after state.B is changed. Also, re-render can be happened when props has been changed @Héctor

Comment: @PatrickBlind, please do the following: (1) Edit your question. (2) Add much much more info about your question, this isn't enough for people to understand. (3) If you have code from your app, add the relevant parts in your question.

Comment: When you do `this.setState({ B: 'newValue' })`, `this.state.A` remains unchanged (and re-render is performed)

Comment: @Héctor Updated the description. hope it does make sense.

Comment: What does `handlepagination()` do exactly?

Comment: @Héctor Thank you. yes, it was resetting state manually. What I wanted to know was that state was reset if component was re-rendered but you gave me the clear understanding.

Comment: Glad to help you!